# How to find out the actual font being rendered by Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-inspector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell which font Chrome is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129966/how-do-i-tell-which-font-chrome-is-using)

I am trying to figure out, using Chrome’s web inspector, what font my site is actually rendering – not simply the CSS font-family spec.

In my case, I happen to know that the first two fonts in the font-family listing are not on my machine. But I shouldn’t have to leave the browser to figure that out. Is there a feature in web inspector, or elsewhere, that offers this?